# How do I print "*" x times in the same row, using methods?

Tags: java, methods, printing

I'm assigned to write a program which prints (x) amount of "*" in a row.

I tried using the "*".repeat(amount) command, but the software wont accept it as a solution.
Also tried using for and while -loops, but I can't figure how to get the *'s be on the same row.

```
public class Tulostelua {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printStarts(3);
    }

    public static void printStart(int amount) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried really ? Because this is just a basic structure ;)

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println` if you don't want to move cursor to next line after printed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use `print` (which doesn't start a new line) or add the chars to a string and `println` that.

So if I understand your question correctly, you need something like this:

```
public void print(int amount) {
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok now I'm feeling such an idiot but well can't really blame myself, the course hasn't spoken anything about other commands than println...

Comment: That's fine! ;D We all have to start somewhere.

Comment: I'm glad I still got such a nice receiving for my question :D I'm ashamed of how long I been trying to solve this..

Comment: Happens to the best of us. ;)
And yes, people can be quite mean on here...

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the accepted answer? Although this might be disabled for duplicate question, I'm not sure.